# Permanently Disable Init Service

Tags: centos, httpd, upstart, init

I just provisioned a new VPS running CentOS 6, and it comes with Apache.

I want to disable Apache, because I will be using Nginx instead.

I know I can just delete the script in /etc/init.d/, but I don't want to do that, because it's a stock thing that came with the system. I would rather have a graceful way of disabling the service.

I thought that I would be able to put something in /etc/inittab, but inittab contains:

```
# inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel.
#
# ADDING OTHER CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.
#
# System initialization is started by /etc/init/rcS.conf
#
# Individual runlevels are started by /etc/init/rc.conf
#
# Ctrl-Alt-Delete is handled by /etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf
#
# Terminal gettys are handled by /etc/init/tty.conf and /etc/init/serial.conf,
# with configuration in /etc/sysconfig/init.
#
# For information on how to write upstart event handlers, or how
# upstart works, see init(5), init(8), and initctl(8).
#
# Default runlevel. The runlevels used are:
#   0 - halt (Do NOT set initdefault to this)
#   1 - Single user mode
#   2 - Multiuser, without NFS (The same as 3, if you do not have networking)
#   3 - Full multiuser mode
#   4 - unused
#   5 - X11
#   6 - reboot (Do NOT set initdefault to this)
# 
id:3:initdefault:
```

This leads me to believe that the system is running upstart. Well, I looked, and the correct way to disable a service in upstart is to add an override file. So I run:

```
% 'manual' > /etc/init/httpd.override
```

And reboot my server. But httpd is still running! Confused by this, I decide to check that upstart is the init service, by running

```
% readlink /proc/1/exe
/sbin/init
```

Well that's not what I was expecting to see. Maybe I'm not running upstart after all. Is there a definite way to check? And if I am running init, what is the recommended way to disable a service permanently? I am new to all this, and there seem to be many conflicting opinions out there.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Why not just remove apache if you are not going to use it?

Comment: Because I might want to use it in the future, for proxying Python applications with mod_wsgi, or running PHP. For now, I don't want to use it. And this seems like a problem I might have again in the future, with different services, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way you disable a service under just about any RedHat-derived distribution is with the `chkconfig` command:

```
# chkconfig httpd off
```

And to stop a running service:

```
# service httpd stop
```

These commands will Do the Right Thing regardless of whether your system is running `systemd`, `upstart`, or vanilla `SysVInit`.

For what it's worth, despite running `upstart` most services in CentOS 6 actually use legacy `init.d` scripts, located in `/etc/rc.d/rc<RUNLEVEL>.d`.  For these services, `chkconfig` manages the symlinks in `/etc/rc.d/init.d`.

Comment: I found this out by searching for something equivalent to update-rc.d from trillan's answer. Was just about to answer my own question, but you beat me to it. Thanks a lot, larsks.

Answer (score 5):

Disable the service you dont want to start during system boot using **chkconfig**.

**List available services with their states**

`chkconfig --list`

**Disable service htttpd in runlevel 2345**

`chkconfig --level 2345 httpd off`